# Change default title of right bar button in PHPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, phpickerviewcontroller, photosui

I'm implementing the new iOS 14 image picker `PHPickerViewController`. By default the right bar button has the title "Add". I want to change this to "Stamp". I tried the code below but it did not work. Does anyone know how to change the right bar button title for `PHPickerViewController`?

```
...          
let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: pickerConfiguartion)
picker.navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Stamp"
```

[image]

Comment: That's not supported. Please file an enhancement request with Apple if you have a good use case!

Comment: By the way, a navigation controller has no navigation item, so even if this were possible, your code would make no sense.

Comment: @matt Good point about the navigation item. I'll open an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: any luck with this?   I have a chat app and love to change the add to send

Comment: @alionthego I'm still using the default "Add" although I have not looked into this recently to see if they have added that functionality.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how Apple's `Messages` app using `PHPickerViewController` without navigation bar! [![IMG-ECC5-A1-E481-DB-1.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/mDZ90GLW/IMG-ECC5-A1-E481-DB-1.jpg)](https://postimg.cc/R38qHyJg)